# How to assign a character based on the number of times it duplicates in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of values that I want to loop through and assign a numerical value starting from 1 on and on. If the same value appears again in the array, I want to append the first value it was assigned with the letter A. If it appears again, I want to append it with the letter B. For example:

```
myArray=[12,15,6,9,11,14,25,6,13,17,6]
```

Expected output should be >>

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
3A
8
9
3B
```

Comment: what code did you try?

Comment: I didn't know what to get to after a basic loop. Basically it would be: let num = 0; for (let i=0;i<myArray.length.i++) { newNum += 1;} but I don't know where the conditional comes in to tell the program hey that number has been here already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work using two maps one for tracking the index of the first occurrence of the element and one for counting how many times the element has appeared previously:

```js
const assignChar = arr => {
  let result = new Array(arr.length)
  let firstOccurenceIndex = {}
  let occurrenceCountMap = {}
  let runningIndex = 1
  arr.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (firstOccurenceIndex[element]) {
      const c = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + occurrenceCountMap[element] - 1)
      result[index] = firstOccurenceIndex[element] + c
    } else {
      firstOccurenceIndex[element] = runningIndex++
      result[index] = firstOccurenceIndex[element]
    }
    occurrenceCountMap[element] = (occurrenceCountMap[element] || 0) + 1
  })
  return result
}

const myArr = [12, 15, 6, 9, 11, 14, 25, 6, 13, 17, 6] 

console.log(assignChar(myArr))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dictionary.

Keep a count variable, which counts how many unique characters you have visited so far and then keep a dictionary where key is the actual number and value is a tuple of assigned number and count of that key so far.

If you can show your own implementation, that way you can be helped better.

Comment: So I would start with an empty object? 

Where in the loop would I incorporate that? 
let num = 0;
let loopdyDoo =() => {
for (let i=0;i < myArray.length;i++) {
num += 1;
//If goes here???